# Finding a Decimal Value Truncated to k Decimal Places

Tags: c, algorithm, runtime-error

Given an integer `k`, it is expected to find the value of the fraction `103993/33102`, truncated upto `k` decimal places. So my approach was the following:

```
    int k ;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    printf("3");
    if(k>0)
    printf(".");
    long long int num=30;
    long long int numer = 1039930;
    long long int denom = 33102;
    while(k--)
    {
        long long int bro = numer/denom;
        printf("%lld",bro-num);
        num=bro;
        num*=10;
        numer*=10;
    }
```

But if `k` is `20` it is showing a weird answer....any problems in the loop?
http://ideone.com/dndib2

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth .... the data type is `long long` and the answer is correct for the smaller than `20` numbers, so I am not able to figure out any possible errors in the loop....;(

Comment: @yobro97 no, your code never gives correct answer. debug it first.

Comment: What are the constraints for k ?

Comment: Sorry guys....didn't think about `10^20`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is overflow.

with `num *= 10;` and `numer *= 10;` in your loop, looping 20 times means 10 ^20 (10 to the power of 20) and with `long long int` being 64 bits it can hold a maximum of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (2^64-1) which is less than 10^20.

Answer (score 5):

As answered above, the `long long int` is overflowing. This shows a similar way by simple longhand division, and you don't even need `long long int` to compute it, let alone try to "fix" it with magic numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int places = 20;
    int numer = 103993;
    int denom = 33102;
    int quot;
    int i;

    // integral part
    quot = numer / denom;
    printf("%d.", quot);
    numer -= denom * quot;

    // fractional part
    for(i=0; i<places; i++) {
        numer *= 10;
        quot = numer / denom;
        printf("%d", quot);
        numer -= denom * quot;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
3.14159265301190260407
```

**Edit**: The only limit to the number of decimal places is the loop control variable size. If you want, the same code will print a *huge* number of decimal places.